# Tracking visualforce page usage

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is there a way to find out the users who have accessed a specific visualforce page?

I think Google analytics is a way to do this(?),but I have not tracked down the page to monitor who accessed the page. Is there any  out of the box/black box feature that will help me know who has accessed a page from the time it was introduced to the present day?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: possibly relevant: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140/how-to-detect-and-block-visual-force-page-from-scraping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is any built-in resource to do this.

You can easily create your own tracking mechanism.  Create an object, let's say *`VF_Tracking__c`*, that has a lookup(User) `User__c`, text(255) `VF_Page_Visited__c`, and dateTime `Datetime_Visited__c` plus anything else you want to track.

In your Visualforce controller, create a pageReference method to track who visits the page, and use it in the **Action** parameter in the `apex:page` compenent in your VF page.

Example:

Controller::

```
public class myVFController{

    public pageReference trackVisits(){
        VF_Tracking__c newTracking = new VF_Tracking__c(User__c=UserInfo.getUserId(),VF_Page_Visited__c='myVFPage',Datetime_Visited__c=datetime.now());
        insert newTracking;
        return null;
    }//END trackVisits

}//END class
```

VF Page (called "myVFPage")

```
<apex:page action="{!trackVisits}">

</apex:page>
```

Comment: I want to know who have visited in the past and I am not concerned about the future visits. Though this solution is awesome it does not help me :(. Thanks for your inputs :)

Comment: Ya, there's no solution for looking back, but you can always implement some code today and be able to answer this question in the future

Comment: I checked with customer success and have confirmed that even internally we don't have a method of tracking VF page usage per user. My one suggestion to the above idea is to make this a custom component so you can just drop it onto any VF page and track that page where needed.

Answer (score 2):

To query metrics on the Visualforce pages in your org, use the **VisualforceAccessMetrics** object in the Salesforce **SOAP API**.

Make a **SOQL** query in Workbench to get information from the VisualforceAccessMetrics object.

The following is a sample SOQL call:

```
SELECT ApexPageId, DailyPageViewCount, Id, ProfileId, MetricsDate, LogDate FROM VisualforceAccessMetrics
```

The following is an example of the query output:
[image]

Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_tools_metrics.htm

Answer (score 1):

you can definitely build a quick custom solution for tracking the page usage using a custom object and some apex coding. But as far as i know there is no OOB solution for tracking this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no feature available that will provide you with historical tracking data. Unless you've had a system in place you can't get data from it, and I've never heard of such a feature being available even internally to Salesforce.com.

The best option is to get tracking in place now rather than later, either using a tool like Google Analytics or a custom one using a quick change to the controller (might be best since you can track users easily across sessions etc.).